# How to add character spacing in SwiftUI after applying fonts and color style?

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I want to add character spacing in the text of **SwiftUI** in iOS version iOS 14 and plus.

When I use a new modifier called as kerning and Tracking after applying fonts styling then it won't work. So any pointer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`kerning` and `tracking` are available in earlier versions of iOS, but **only** if they're applied directly to `Text` views.

What's new in iOS 16 is the ability to apply the modifier to any view, and have it apply to any of its Text child views.

Note the availability flags for `Text.tracking` vs `View.tracking`:

- [`Text.tracking(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/tracking(_:)#) - iOS 13.0+, macOS 10.15+
- [`View.tracking(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tracking(_:)#) - iOS 16.0+, macOS 13.0+

So that means that this should work for you in iOS 14:

```swift
Text("My Sample Text")
  .tracking(-0.1)
```

but this would not:

```swift
VStack {
  Text("My Sample View")
  Text("With two lines of text")
}
.tracking(-0.1)
```